# Validate fetch Request response from few 3rd party APIs using NEST.js DTO and Decorators

Tags: node.js, api, entity, typeorm, nest

How to validate fetch Request incoming data from few 3rd party APIs  using NEST.js DTO and Decorators. How can I in a good way map data incoming from these APIS into one format and save into the same table ?

Comment: At first you can check if these 3rd party APIs have some typescript client/sdk available on npm. If not, you can take a look at their docs and create interfaces yourself by copypasting examples from the documentation with this [tool](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=ts)

Comment: @MichałSkorzec ok lets say I am creating Interfaces for each request, that is the usual thing we do, but how can I validate it by DTO ? imagine you make get request and need to pass validation for incoming data.

Comment: Well, that depends on your level of strictness. You have three options -
1) trust their documentation and don't validate, or
2) validate with `class-validator` for example, throw errors and risk not always having data in your preferred format.
3) validate silently and try to parse when something is off.

Just to double check - by incoming data from 3rd party APIs, do you mean requesting them for the data (for ex. with `axios`) or an incoming webhook from them to your api?

Comment: @MichałSkorzec yes you are right requesting it via axios for example. Could you please give me an example how can I do that using axios ? I mean validating incoming data using class-valdaitor or some other decorators ?